# Second homology of mapping class group via universal coefficient theorem

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, mapping-class-groups

Let $S_g$ be the closed, orientable surface of genus $g\ge 2$ and $Mod(S_{g,1})$ the mapping class group of homeomorphisms fixing a base point $x_0\in S_g$ modulo isotopies fixing $x_0$.

It is known that $$H^2(Mod(S_{g,1});{\mathbf Z})\simeq{\mathbf Z}^2$$ is generated by the **Euler class** and the class of the **Meyer signature cocycle**.

A nontrivial argument invoking the universal coefficient theorem shows that then $$H_2(Mod(S_{g,1});{\mathbf Z})\simeq{\mathbf Z}^2,$$
see e.g. p.167 in [Farb-Margalit's book](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/farbmarg.pdf).

Question: *Can one give explicit descriptions (in terms of the bar resolution) of cycles representing generators that (under the universal coefficient theorem's isomorphism) correspond to Euler class and Meyer signature cocycle (or some other generators)?*

There is an equivalent, perhaps more intuitive, formulation of this question. Namely, one can represent any homology class $c\in H_2(S_{g,1};{\mathbf Z})$ by a surface $S_h$ (of sufficiently high genus $h$) in the following sense: there is a map $B\rho\colon S_h\to BMod(S_{g,1})$ such that
$$c=(B\rho)_*\left[S_h\right]$$
for the fundamental class $S_h\in H_2(S_h;{\mathbf Z})$. (We denote by $B\Gamma$ the classifying space of a discrete group $\Gamma$ and by $B\rho$ the map corresponding to a homomorphism $\rho$.) Then the question can be rephrased as follows:

*Does one know two homomorphisms $\rho_1,\rho_2\colon\pi_1S_h\to Mod(S_{g,1})$ (for suitable $h$) such that the two elements 
$$(B\rho_1)_*\left[S_h\right], (B\rho_2)_*\left[S_h\right]$$
generate $H_2(Mod(S_{g,1});{\mathbf Z})$?*